# SonarQube - Module Configuration - classes missing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have a multi-module Java Project with the following configuration (simplified):

```
sonar.java.binaries=classes
sonar.java.test.binaries=classes
sonar.java.libraries=../**/*.jar, ../../**/*.jar, ../../../**/*.jar
sonar.java.test.libraries=../**/*.jar, ../../**/*.jar, ../../../**/*.jar

sonar.tests=testsrc
sonar.sources=src

sonar.modules=moduleA, moduleB, moduleC

moduleA.sonar.projectBaseDir=project/moduleA
moduleB.sonar.projectBaseDir=project/subfolder/moduleB
moduleC.sonar.projectBaseDir=project/subfolder/anothersubfolder/moduleC
```

All modules have dependencies on each other (e.g. moduleA uses classes from moduleB uses classes from moduleC)

Now I get the following Warning:

```
The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
....
....
```

I solved the Problem by adding the missing binaries folders for the modules e.g.

```
moduleA.sonar.java.binaries=classes, ../subfolder/moduleB/classes, ../subfolder/anothersubfolder/moduleC
```

but as far as my project consists of MANY modules (nearly 100) I don't want to add every depending module manually

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using SonarQube 7.1 and SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1

Comment: Is this by chance a Maven project? A Gradle project?

Comment: It's a gradle project, but I'm using SonarQubeScanner for the analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my project consists of MANY modules (nearly 100) I don't want to add every depending module manually
>
> What am I doing wrong here?

We established in the comments that you're using the vanilla SonarQube Scanner to analyze a Gradle project. ... *That's* what you're doing wrong.

Will it still work to use the vanilla scanner on a Gradle project? Sure. It's working now.

But as you've discovered, you'll have to do all the configuration manually of all the layout that Gradle already knows about. If you don't want to do that configuration for 100 modules, then you should look into [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle)